# What "management by discomfort" is?

Tags: team-management, project-management-style

I've just read about [*management by discomfort*](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/has-elon-musks-management-discomfort-gone-too-far-lynne-everatt) that Elon Musk uses:

> The challenge is he is a machine and the rest of us aren't. So if you
>   work for Elon, you have to accept the discomfort. But in that
>   discomfort is the kind of growth you can't get anywhere else.

It seems to me that this kind of motivation is not something new and is used in a lot of companies. At the same time I can't find any references by searching the web for the relevant keywords.

What "management by discomfort" is?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the term only exists in the referenced article and this question, according to Google. So it is a neologism created by the author of the article rather than a standard management doctrine or technique. Could also be off-topic as "Opinion based" for the same reason.

Comment: @MarvMills It could be that there is a more common term for this neologism.

Comment: @bahrep Yes it could be, however that would be speculation and opinion-based. Since this is an invented term, apparently not used elsewhere, there can be no canonical answer to the question "What is management by discomfort". Can there? There can, of course, be interpretation and discussion- but that is not what this site is for.

Comment: VtC on the grounds that this is not a project management question as defined in [ask]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if it's an actual management framework or encapsulated approach, but my takeaway is that working for him is simply challenging in terms of expectations and effort. People tend to grow when challenged at just the right amounts, as they stretch themselves to match the environment (think of athletes competing among those slightly better than themselves). And the sad truth is that many orgs still don't challenge their employees in ways that engage and grow them.